# SQL connection throws error when adding DistributedSession, SessionMiddleware

Tags: sql-server, google-kubernetes-engine, distributed-system, distributed-caching, msal

Application Info -

c# .net8 Dapper

Use Case -

Trying to use MSAL with distributed caching as sql

Application works fine locally but when deployed to Kubernetes it throw below error -

```
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
     at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.EnableSsl(UInt32 info, SqlConnectionEncryptOption encrypt, Boolean integratedSecurity, String serverCertificateFilename)
     at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(SqlConnectionEncryptOption encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean& marsCapable, Boolean& fedAuthRequired, Boolean tlsFirst, String serverCert)
     at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Boolean withFailover)
     at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
     at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
     at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
     at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool)
     at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
     at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
     at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
     at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
     at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
     at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
     at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer.DatabaseOperations.GetCacheItemAsync(String key, Boolean includeValue, CancellationToken token)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer.DatabaseOperations.RefreshCacheItemAsync(String key, CancellationToken token)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer.SqlServerCache.RefreshAsync(String key, CancellationToken token)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession.CommitAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
  ClientConnectionId:f5888c74-0cab-48c8-a5b1-3d9f7ecc5ce1
  Error Number:-2146893019,State:0,Class:20
```

DB connection works fine if I try to fetch some data but with session and distributed cache it fails with error.
Connection string looks like, DB is inside a VM -

```
xx.xxx.x.x,xxxx;Database=DBName;User Id=abc;Password=xyz
```

Code which is used for adding distributed cache is as follow -

```
builder.Services
    .AddLogging()
    .AddDistributedMemoryCache()
    .AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options =>
    {
        options.ConnectionString = config;
        options.SchemaName = "dbo";
        options.TableName = "TokenCache";
        options.DefaultSlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
    });

builder.Services.Configure<MsalDistributedTokenCacheAdapterOptions>(options =>
{
    // Optional: Disable the L1 cache in apps that don't use session affinity
    //                 by setting DisableL1Cache to 'true'.
    options.DisableL1Cache = false;

    // Or limit the memory (by default, this is 500 MB)
    options.L1CacheOptions.SizeLimit = 500; // 1 GB

    // You can choose if you encrypt or not encrypt the cache
    options.Encrypt = false;

    // And you can set eviction policies for the distributed
    // cache.
    options.SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
});
```

Found another error might be related -

```
fail: Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenCacheProviders.Distributed.MsalDistributedTokenCacheAdapter[103]
  [MsIdWeb] DistributedCache: Write Connection issue. InRetry? False Error message: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught) 
  Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
   ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.
     at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
     at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle.EnableSsl(UInt32 options)
     at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
     at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
     at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
     at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
     at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.InternalOpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
     at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer.DatabaseOperations.SetCacheItemAsync(String key, Byte[] value, DistributedCacheEntryOptions options, CancellationToken token)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer.SqlServerCache.SetAsync(String key, Byte[] value, DistributedCacheEntryOptions options, CancellationToken token)
     at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenCacheProviders.Utility.Measure(Task task)
     at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenCacheProviders.Distributed.MsalDistributedTokenCacheAdapter.L2OperationWithRetryOnFailureAsync(String operation, Func`2 cacheOperation, String cacheKey, Byte[] bytes, Boolean inRetry)
  ClientConnectionId:cf6f7680-cd59-47fd-9c80-a765527b0b30
  Error Number:-2146893019,State:0,Class:20
```

I'm sure it has something to do with Distributed cache sql connection, possibly it take connection string in different way or something, same connection string in Dapper works.

Comment: Is `xx.xxx.x.x,xxxx` an SQL Server instance that's still using its default self-signed certificate for encrypted connections? Assuming you're using exactly the same connection string in both places... did you configure your own computer to trust that certificate?

Comment: yes, both connection strings are exactly the same, I'll check on certificate and will get back to u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue, very silly thing actually, I just needed to add
`Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True`.

Dapper connection works fine without this but SQL Distributed cache doesn't.